# Inserting multiple rows mysql in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

i am trying to insert multiple rows at once using Codeigniter

my html code for codeigniter view

```
     <?= form_open(base_url() . 'home/create') ?>
            <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td class="col-md-1 center-block">
                        <input type="text" name="id[]" value="1" class="form-control" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="enter descreption" class="form-control" name="desc[]" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-md-2 center-block">
                        <input id="space"  onkeyup="sumPrice()" type="number" class="form-control" name="space[]" />
                    </td>
                    <td> 
                        <select onchange="sumPrice()" class="selectpicker price" data-live-search="true" data-width="100%" name="price[]" data-header="Select cost"> 
                            <option value="5">5</option> 
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="20">20</option>
                        </select>
                    </td> 
                    <td class="total_price col-md-1">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="total[]" value="1000" />
                    </td> 
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger center-block  remove-row"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Remove</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="insert" class="btn btn-success" />
    </form>
    <button class="btn btn-success append-row"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add new row</button>
```

and i am using jQuery to insert new row in the table
here is `js` the code

```
    $('.append-row').click(function() {
    $("table tbody").append
    ('<tr><td class="col-md-1 center-block"><input type="text" name="id[]" value="' + row_id_val++ + '" class="form-control" /></td> <td><input type="text" placeholder="enter descreption" class="form-control" name="desc[]" /></td> <td class="col-md-2 center-block"><input id="space"  onkeyup="sumPrice()" type="number" class="form-control" name="space[]" /></td> <td> <select onchange="sumPrice()" class="selectpicker price" data-live-search="true" data-width="100%" name="price[]" data-header="Select Sub account" onselect="sumPrice()" > <option onselect="sumPrice()" value="5">5</option> <option onselect="sumPrice()" value="10">10</option> <option onselect="sumPrice()" value="20">20</option> </select> </td> <td class="total_price col-md-1"><input type="number" class="form-control" value=""  name="total[]" /></td> <td><button class="btn btn-danger center-block  remove-row"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Remove</button></td></tr>');
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
});
```

my controller

```
if ($_POST) {
    $data = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->input->post('id')); $i++) {
        $data[$i] = array(
            'row_id' => $this->input->post('id')[$i],
            'desc' => $this->input->post('desc')[$i],
            'space' => $this->input->post('space')[$i],
            'price' => $this->input->post('price')[$i],
            'total' => $this->input->post('total')[$i],
            'code' => time()
        );
    }
    $this->Home_model->create($data);
}
```

model

```
function create($data) {
    $this->db->insert_batch('quotation', $data);
}
```

i tried too many solutions from stackoverflow but none of them worked

Comment: what is your php version?if your php version lower than 5.4 your code will not work

Comment: @ShaifulIslam  PHP Version 5.4.19

Comment: your submitting only one array set... how come you expect multiple rows will be inserted....

Comment: i am appending new rows when i click on the button @BharathiRaja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your php version>=5.4 it should work.
You may try this

```
    if ($_POST) 
    {
        $row_ids=$this->input->post('id');
        $desc=$this->input->post('desc');
        $spaces=$this->input->post('space');
        $prices=$this->input->post('price');
        $totals=$this->input->post('total');
        $data = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->input->post('id')); $i++)
        {
            $data[$i] = array(
                'row_id' => $row_ids[$i],
                'desc' => $desc[$i],
                'space' => $spaces[$i],
                'price' => $prices[$i],
                'total' => $totals[$i],
                'code' => time()
            );
        }
        $this->Home_model->create($data);
    }
```

Comment: can you please print the $data before sending it to model?it seems your data array is not producing properly or you getting some error.If you get any error what error you getting.Write the full error message.

Comment: result of printing the array before sending it to model `Array ( [0] => Array ( [row_id] => 1 [desc] => test [space] => 10 [price] => 5 [total] => 50 [code] => 1427544624 ) )`

Comment: something wrong with the array , it comes one time only what's wring ?

Comment: if you using this code print out the `count($row_ids)` and `count($this->input->post('id'))` what value u getting?if you getting both value 1 then update your question with full view codes

Answer (score 3):

Can you please try below given code? I think there may be issue with $data.

```
if ($_POST) {
        $data = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->input->post('id')); $i++) {
            $data[] = array(
                'row_id' => $this->input->post('id')[$i],
                'desc' => $this->input->post('desc')[$i],
                'space' => $this->input->post('space')[$i],
                'price' => $this->input->post('price')[$i],
                'total' => $this->input->post('total')[$i],
                'code' => time()
            );
        }
        $this->Home_model->create($data);
    }
```

Comment: owww...getting any error while query execution OR can you diagnose the problem by printing query?

Comment: it gives me `Message: Undefined offset: 1` also it insert only one row in database and the other rows are empty no data

Comment: okay..diagnose it by printing $data value..put die() before $this->Home_model->create($data) statement..there is issue with your data array..also print the $this->input->post('id')[$i] as you have put loop boundary on it.

Comment: have you printed the `$data` and seen does it has required data..... or print the `count($this->input->post('id'))`  and check the count is correct

Comment: i have printed `echo count($this->input->post('id'))` after the loop but the result is 1 although its more than it

Comment: Just for testing purpose..can you please use $PostId = $_POST['id'] and then print_r($PostId) and count($PostId) the post variable. I think you are very near to solve your problem.

Comment: i have tested it using `print_r($PostId) ` the result is one array `Array ( [0] => 1 ) 1` !!

Answer (score 0):

Try add enctype="multipart/form-data" in your tag form